Random order for serde_json::to_string_pretty()
I have a struct with a function that returns a String from a json using serde_json::to_string_pretty(). I am trying to write a unit test to verify the output of the string.
 #[test]
    fn test() {
        ...
        let j =
            json!({
            "mock_key": "val",
            "another_key": "another_val",
        });
        assert_eq!(serde_json::to_string_pretty(&j).unwrap(), json_string);

When I run the test, it passed for the first time. And if I try to run the test for the second time , the test fails because:
Diff < left / right > :
 {
<  "mock_key": "val",
<  "another_key": "another_val"
>  "another_key": "another_val",
>  "mock_key": "val"
 }

If I try to run it again, the test passes, and the cycle continues.
Why is that? And is there a better way to do it?
I tried changing the order in let j = json!({...}).
The test should pass (or fail) each time I run it with no changes made to the code.
I have also enabled the preserve_order feature in dependencies.

Does the type you're serializing to create json_string use HashMap or BTreeMap? It seems like your code itself is probably generating JSON with unordered keys.

It uses HashMap to create the json_string. I have already enabled the preserve_order and judging from the output the order for the json_string seems to be the same every time, so I think the problem lies within serde_json::to_string_prettier().

The best way will be to compare the objects instead of strings.

The serde_json crate assumes by default that items in JSON objects are in arbitrary order. You can turn on the preserve_order feature to avoid this.
You can turn on Cargo features by either running a Cargo command or by editing your Cargo.toml manually:
cargo add serde_json -F preserve_order

[dependencies]
serde_json = { version = "1", features = ["preserve_order"] }


Alternatively, do it only for dev-dependencies.

I have enabled this feature already. Sorry for not mentioning this in the post.
